# Salesforce CI/CD Pipeline with Github Actions

Tags: salesforce, github-actions, continuous-deployment, cicd

Please help me with this UseCase. Thanks for any help in advance.

I am creating some Salesforce project in VS Code. I have cloned the repository and pushed it in Github. I have three branches in the repo named as Feature, Developer and Master. Feature is the base branch. Whenever I change or write a code, on deployment it is pushed to Feature.

Now I want that there should be Dev org attached to Developer branch as well and whenever a code after testing is pushed from Feature to Developer branch, or I pull the code to Developer from Feature, all the code shall be deployed to the attached org.
And similarly on pushing the code from Developer to Master.

I wrote the workflow rule and did it nearly.But On creating a pull req, the workflow was working but it was showing error while build and deploy and decryption was failing with error something like that- can't read the directory. Lastly, when I removed encrypt Decrypt keys, Authorization step is not passing and showing the same endless error- OAuth client secret of personal connected app?: sh: 1: read: Illegal option -s.

So the youtube video I followed confused me while encrypting server key. He got some hashkey and hash IV from somewhere and generated new hash key and hash IV to generate some server.key.enc

Comment: Welcome to SO @Shubhendra Shukla. Please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

What tutorial(?) are you following? I don't recognise steps about decrypting keys, it might be some old or overcomplicated method.

There's cool blog post at https://tigerfacesystems.com/blog/sfdx-continuous-integration and/or you can look what SF does themselves in the LWC recipes repository (you know, the one to which most of LWC documentation points to): https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml

You'd have to login with sfdx to all target orgs you need, use that "sfdx force:org:display" and "Sfdx Auth Url" trick, save each org's value as different Github variable and create similar scripts.