# Deploy changes from GitHub to Salesforce

Tags: github, salesforce, github-actions

How can I add a custom button on GitHub.com which I could click on in order to deploy changes from the Master branch to a related Salesforce.com DEV Org?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/73149247/313628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried? Have you seen https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/01/using-salesforce-dx-with-github-actions ?

You can steal sample actions from SF official repo at https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes.

You'll need to provide the secret login URL to your target org, there are blog posts how to generate it and store in GitHub variable, for example https://tigerfacesystems.com/blog/sfdx-continuous-integration/ or https://github.com/sfdx-actions/setup-sfdx

Last but not least - to have action available for manual run (not just automated) read up about "workflow_dispatch"

Comment: I am trying to understand https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/01/using-salesforce-dx-with-github-actions but ... I do not understand the syntax of the examples. I have sent you an invitation to connect through LinkedIn in case you can.

Comment: I do not understand the dependency on npm and node.js (I have never used these before)